# npgsql schema "dbo" does not exist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dbcontext, npgsql

i have a problem similar to [Entity Framework 5.0 PostgreSQL (Npgsql) default connection factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14690567/entity-framework-5-0-postgresql-npgsql-default-connection-factory)

I have Npgsql declared in app.config :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="monDbContexte" 
         connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=ma_datab_db;User Id=postgres;Password=root;" 
     providerName="Npgsql" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <!-- le factory provider -->
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" 
           invariant="Npgsql" 
           support="FF" 
           description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Postgresql Server" 
           type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

my context provider class:

```
public class ContextDB: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Personne> Personnes { get; set; }

    public ContextDB()
        : base("monDbContexte")
    {
    }
}
```

my "Personne" Class:

[Table("personnes", Schema = "public")]
    public class Personne
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("id_personne")]
        [Display(Name="Identifiant")]
        public int id { get; set; }

```
    [Column("nom")]
    [Display(Name = "Nom")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Merci de saisir le nom.")]
    public string Nom { get; set; }

    [Column("prenom")]
    [Display(Name = "Prénom")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Merci de saisir le prénom.")]
    public string Prenom { get; set; }
...
...
}
```

and in my controller action i do something like this:

```
            using (var context = new ContextDB())
            {
                // *** here i have an exception...
                var personnes = from p in context.Personnes
                              where p.Nom.StartsWith("m")
                              orderby p.Nom
                              select new { p.Nom, p.Prenom };

                foreach (var une_personne in personnes)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(une_personne.Nom + " " + une_personne.Prenom);
                }
```

after this i have an exception like this :

```
ERROR: schema "dbo" does not exist
```

this is an NpgsqlException

[french]
    ERREUR: 3F000: le schéma « dbo » n'existe pas

i dont undersand what's wrong in this

EDIT:

this is the exception :
(sorry but it is in french)

PS : i have no projects in "**C:\projects\Npgsql2**" and i have nothing like this path in my current project, so what is this??

```
L'exception Npgsql.NpgsqlException n'a pas été gérée par le code utilisateur
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=ERREUR: 3F000: le schéma « dbo » n'existe pas
  Source=Npgsql
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  BaseMessage=le schéma « dbo » n'existe pas
  Code=3F000
  Detail=""
  ErrorSql=SELECT "GroupBy1"."A1" AS "C1" FROM (SELECT CAST (count(1) AS int4) AS "A1" FROM "dbo"."__MigrationHistory" AS "Extent1Group") AS "GroupBy1"
  File=src\backend\catalog\namespace.c
  Hint=""
  Line=2826
  Position=82
  Routine=get_namespace_oid
  Severity=ERREUR
  Where=""
  StackTrace:
       à Npgsql.NpgsqlState.<ProcessBackendResponses_Ver_3>d__a.MoveNext() dans C:\projects\Npgsql2\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlState.cs:ligne 850
       à Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader.GetNextResponseObject() dans C:\projects\Npgsql2\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlDataReader.cs:ligne 1173
       à Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader.GetNextRowDescription() dans C:\projects\Npgsql2\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlDataReader.cs:ligne 1191
       à Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader.NextResult() dans C:\projects\Npgsql2\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlDataReader.cs:ligne 1377
       à Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader..ctor(IEnumerable`1 dataEnumeration, CommandBehavior behavior, NpgsqlCommand command, NotificationThreadBlock threadBlock, Boolean synchOnReadError) dans C:\projects\Npgsql2\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlDataReader.cs:ligne 1040
       à Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.GetReader(CommandBehavior cb) dans C:\projects\Npgsql2\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlCommand.cs:ligne 611
       à Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cb) dans C:\projects\Npgsql2\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlCommand.cs:ligne 588
       à Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) dans C:\projects\Npgsql2\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlCommand.cs:ligne 538
       à System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
       à System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Did you get it working with the Alamakanambra tip? About the c:\projects path, this is the path the Npgsql developer used to compile Npgsql. You don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 5):

It seems EF uses dbo as the default schema for database. You need to change it to "public" which is the default schema for Postgresql.

You use that by importing the namespace:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

And annotate your classes to use a different schema:

```
[Table("mytable", Schema = "public")]
Class test {...}
```

For more information, check out my post about EF and Npgsql: http://fxjr.blogspot.com/2013/06/npgsql-code-first-entity-framework-431.html

I hope it helps.

Comment: am already using this annotations. The funny part is my y application is runnig fine! dont ask me how i dont know :p, it seems to pass through this exception, and when am in debug mode i press F5 two times and the error is ignored (thanks Francisco Junior)

Comment: Those 2 exceptions you are getting is about the __MigrationHistory query EF does when starting your application. They are ignored by Entity Framework but you still receive the notification about them when debugging your application in VS.Net. I think I still need to add more support in Npgsql so those queries about history migration works ok. But for while, as history migration support isn't implemented in Npgsql, there is no side effects about those 2 errors. I'm glad you get it working ok.

Comment: thanks @Francisco-Junior you help me a lot, am waiting for the Npgsql next version

Comment: but with mysql it works, this dbo. issue may be a postgres driver thing

Answer (score 5):

I used  [EntitiyFramework6 6.2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/),  [EntityFramework6.Npgsql v3.2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework6.Npgsql/) and [Npgsql 4.0.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/)

on your Context class add `modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("public");` in `OnModelCreating` function.

For example;

```
public class ContextDB: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Personne> Personnes { get; set; }

    public ContextDB()
        : base("monDbContexte")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("public");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: `modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("");` also works, this will use the current PG schema.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.
Dont know why, but when I didnt use `Database.SetInitializer` in `Application_Start()` method it is just fine.
So:

```
//Database.SetInitializer<ContextDB>(new ContextDBInitializer());
```

Comment: actualy i dont use this line. BUT when i continue debuging (F5 two times) VS seems to ignore this exception an run the code correctly. BIZAR! (thans Alamakanambra & Francisco Junior)

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
public class PostgisDbContext : DbContext
{
    public PostgisDbContext() : base("Postgis")
    {
        //begin
        try
        {
            this.Database.Initialize(false); issue
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {}
        //end
    }
}
```

It may be imperfect but it works.